# I have rotating wheels on a car, but I want them rotate the other way. What do I need to change?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my javascript code. I have used this code on 2 images of wheels to make it seem they rotate. So with this code the images rotate to the right but I want them to go left. Is there anyway I can change it in this code? Thanks!

```
var looper;
var degrees = 359;
function rotateAnimation(el,speed){
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    if(navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome")){
        elem.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Firefox")){
        elem.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE")){
        elem.style.msTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Opera")){
        elem.style.OTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    } else {
        elem.style.transform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    }
    looper = setTimeout('rotateAnimation(\''+el+'\','+speed+')',speed);
    degrees++;
    if(degrees > 359){
        degrees = 1;
    }
    // document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
}
```

Comment: var degrees = -359;

Comment: I think - it makes sense though

Comment: I literally found out 20 seconds after i posted it. Thanks though!

Comment: remember to fix degrees-- and the conditions for resetting

Comment: I changed this: degrees--;
 if(degrees < -359){
  degrees = -1;

Comment: Actually only changing the ++ into -- helped. Thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the degrees negative:

```
elem.style.transform = "rotate(-"+degrees+"deg)";
```